# my xpath is not working

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to grab data from something that looks like this:

```
<html>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <div>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <div>
```

I think this is basically what I was looking at earlier, so I did `$x('//table/tr/td/div')`. This returned like 10 divs, all the ones I wanted. However, I couldn't find a way to navigate through these 10 divs. Wouldn't it just be `$x('//table/tr/td/div[?]')`, where ? can be 1-10? BTW this is a dynamic table, each div is a different module to navigate to a part of the page, so I am trying to automate logging in and going to a certain module, yet I can only select all 10 and not a single module. In this html, div 1 and div 2 would be something like "security module" and "ticketing module".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First just a heads up, you may want to try Firebug+Firepath on Firefox, which is a more handy tool than Chrome's developer tool.

For your question, you can do this either by xpath or Selenium

Using Xpath's index (starts from one), say you want the 2nd:

```python
# second div's xpath: (//table/tr/td/div)[2]
second_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table/tr/td/div)[2]")
```

Using Selenium's index (i.e get all ten divs from your xpath, then index them starting from zero):

```python
all_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tr/td/div") # all_divs should have 10 elements
second_div = all_divs[1] # zero-based index
```

Comment: awesome thanks, I cant test it right now but looks like it will work perfectly